# MVC 5 App with Google OAuth2 Sign-on (C#) is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

I have followed some articles, but all are not clear as google oauth interface is changed.

Verified some articles, and understood something. With this understanding in mind, followed below steps:

Opned URL: `console.developers.google.com`

Created new project with name: **My Super App**

Clicked on **Google+ API** under Overview section, and Enabled the same.

***Here is my doubt whether I am doing correct or not***

Selected **OAuth ClientID** option under **Credentials** section.

Configured **Consent screen** With email address, and Product name.

Under **Create Client ID** section, provided below details:

**Application type**: Web Application

**Name**: My Super Client App

**Authorized Javascript origins**: http://localhost:44300/ **- sometimes, I have used this option. Later on, now, I am not using this option. Please suggest me if it is mandatory.**

**Authorized redirect URIs:** http://localhost:44300/signin-google

**ClientID, ClientSecret** have been generated. Used in My MVC app.

But, I am unable to use Google OAuth.

Please suggest me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: First, use https (ssl), not http. Second what mean 'not working'? Any error, exception, message, anything?

Comment: A bit of your code would actually help.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your Project properties and under the Web tab you'll see the Project URL. In place of the https://localhost:44300/ given in the article replace it with the one specified in Project URL or, if you've overridden that one, use the one specified in the Override application root URL.

In other words, you shall change the URL here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion but perhaps you need to enable the api on your google developer console. I did a quick google and this covers it - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-configure-google-sign-in-for-Asp-Net-mvc-5-part-sixt/

Answer (score 0):

please follow [Asp.net/mvc :MVC5 :Google OpenAuth](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#goog) from where the below steps are taken:

Creating a Google app for OAuth 2 and connecting the app to the project

1. Navigate to the Google Developers Console.
2. Click the Create **Project**
   button and enter a project name and ID (you can use the default
   values). In a few seconds the new project will be created and your
   browser will display the new projects page.
3. In the left tab, click
   **APIs & auth**, and then >  **Credentials.**
4. Click the **Create New Client ID**
   under **OAuth**. In the Create Client ID dialog, keep the default Web
   application for the application type.
5. Set the **Authorized JavaScript**
   origins to the SSL URL you used above **(https://localhost:44300/
   unless you've created other SSL projects)** Set the **Authorized
   redirect** URI to:
        https://localhost:44300/signin-google
6. Click the Consent screen menu item, then set your email address and product name. When you
   have completed the form click Save.
   Click the APIs menu item, scroll
   down and switch on Google+ API.
7. Copy and paste the AppId and App Secret  into the `UseGoogleAuthentication` method.  The AppId and App Secret values shown below are samples and will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your try, but NOT working. Have you tried by doing like this before you submit answer to me? I am asking this question; why because, whatever the steps you have mentioned are NOT as per console.developers.google.com user interface. Now, the interface is little bit changed. I guess, you have NOT tried recently.